# Angular 4 vertical scrolling calendar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Hi I want to use calendar for my application (for mobile view) but it
needs to be vertical scrolling how can I achieve this?

I'm using angular material.io but for scrolling to next month the are using arrow button on top but I need, if we scroll calendar from top
to bottom it need to show next month.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: I just want a date picker with vertical scrolling using angular 4,i have used angular material but for month scrolling they are using a button but i'm building web application for mobile view and i want vertical scrolling so i can   switch to next month by scrolling

Comment: @kishore Have you found any solution for this?